# How do I disable horizontal scroll in UIScrollView on an iPad?

Tags: ipad, uiscrollview, horizontal-scrolling

I only want to activate vertical but not horizontal scrolling. How can I achieve this in the [`UIScrollView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html) class?

Comment: Did you read the docs before coming to ask this question? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006922-CH3-SW28 - have a look at the `showsHorizontalScrollIndicator` property. If that isn't working for you then perhaps you could expand your question explaining why.

Comment: His question is about disabling scrolling. Not showing the horizontal indicator does not disable scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of `contentSize` property of the UIScrollView.

For example, if your scrollView size is 260 pixels wide,then

```
CGSize scrollArea = CGSizeMake(260, scrollableHeight); //you can use yourScrollView.width instead of 260 if you assigned its frame already.
[yourScrollView setContentSize: scrollArea];
```